# How to include a Node.js module using a relative path with Electron-builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

So basically a have a Node.js module that is required using:

```
var parse = require("csv-parse/lib/sync");
```

The problem is that when my project is built with Electron-Builder and NSIS, the module cannot be found. Likely due to the file path being completely different after the project is packaged and build.

Listing it as a dependency doesn't help.

What's the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) would resolve that issue. Or you could try [eletron-forge](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge) which uses eletron-compile. I've used electron-forge in the passed and it works great